# How to Copy a file to another directory after submit

Tags: php, function, copy

I am trying to create a directory after a form submit, then after the form is submitted I want that directory to have a file stuffed inside of it. I have tried the php copy function and used an if statement to see if it was copying successfully but it is not. Please take a look at my code and see what is going on. And when it was working, it would just give a "1" output once submitted. No actual file was moved inside of the folder.

```
if($_POST['submit']=='Register')
{
// If the Register form has been submitted
$root = "/serves/registered.php";
$err = array();
$folder = mkdir($_POST['username']);
$reg = "registered.php";
mkdir($_POST['username']);
copy($root,$folder);
if (!copy($root, $folder)) {
        echo "failed to copy $root...\n";
} else {
    echo "Account was successfuly created.";
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Why on the earth do you do the copy twice?

Comment: To move files/folders you can use the `rename` function. But I don't understand what are you trying to do. Why do you `mkdir($_POST['username'])` and `copy($root,$folder)` twice?

Comment: @HtmHell right that is the username the user is creating, and in turn that will create a new directory with his username he has chosen. Now we want a file inside of that directory on the submit button has been clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can do it:

```
$root = "serves/registered.php";
$folder = mkdir($_POST['username']);
if($folder) {
    $reg = "registered.php";
    if (!copy($root, $_POST['username']."/".$reg)) {
        echo "failed to copy $root...\n";
    } else {
        echo "Account was successfuly created.";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Could not create folder";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST['submit']=='Register')
{
    // If the Register form has been submitted
    $root = "contact.php";
    $folder = $_POST['username'] . '/' . $root;
    mkdir($_POST['username']);
    if (!copy($root, $folder)) {
      echo "failed to copy $root...\n";
    } else {
     echo "Account was successfuly created.";
    }
}
```